# Creating a Makefile for jar executable

Tags: java, command-line, jar, makefile

I am currently working with the following Makefile:

```
    JAVAC=javac
    sources = $(wildcard *.java)
    classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

    all: myProgram

    myProgram: $(classes)

    clean :
        rm -f *.class

    %.class : %.java
        $(JAVAC) $<
```

myProgram was orignally just a .java file, but I've replaced it with a .jar executable.  I still essentially just want to be able to do something simple like:

```
    make myProgram
```

How can I modify my Makefile to accomplish this?  Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new target (e.g. "jar"), and give it the appropriate "jar" command

EXAMPLE:

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: myProgram

myProgram: $(classes)

clean :
    rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
    $(JAVAC) $<

jar: $(classes)
    jar cvf myjarfile.jar $(classes)
```

You can "tweak" this example many ways.  For example, you might want to parameterize the "jar" command (e.g. `JAR=jar`), you might want to create a manifest (perhaps have the makefile itself create a manifest on-the-fly with appropriate "echo" commands), etc. etc.

Here is the Oracle documentation for "jar":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Declare `jar` as [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) and have it depend on the output `myjarfile.jar` file and then add a target for that file which depends on `$(classes)`. That's better general practice.

Answer (score 1):

the code above doesn't working here for me, I make some changes with manifest file:

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: myProgram

myProgram: $(classes)

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) $<

jar:    
    @echo "Manifest-Version: 1.0" > manifest.txt
    @echo "Class-Path: ." >> manifest.txt
    @echo "Main-Class: Main" >> manifest.txt
    @echo "" >> manifest.txt

    jar -cmf manifest.txt JARNAME.jar $(classes)

clean:
    rm -f *.class
    rm manifest.txt
```